# Self-invoking function inside DOMContentLoaded event - sense?

Tags: javascript, scope

Since I want my JS to run only after DOMContentLoaded I do it like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    //
});
```

Since I want to limit scope level and it's in general a good practice to enclose code into anonymous function, I do it like this:

```
(function() {
    //
})();
```

So, does it make sense to write code like this?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    (function() {
        //
    })();
});
```

Comment: That depends on the use case, but ES6 block scoped variable declarations (`const` and `let`) have significantly reduced the need of IIFEs inside functions.

Comment: No, it really doesn't make sense. It just unnecessarily introduces a nested scope and more indentation. For which things in particular do you want to "limit scope level" and how?

Comment: No, it is not "*in general a good practice to enclose code into anonymous function*". It is a good practice to specifically give code *that needs it* its own scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of an **Immediately Invoked Functional Expression** is to provide namespacing to avoid polluting the global scope. Since `document` is already a global variable it makes sense to put it outside like you did which will allow you to write more IIFEs in the same `DOMContentLoaded` callback like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // IIFE 1
    (function() {

    })();

   // IIFE 2
   (function() {

   })();

   ...

});
```

Comment: Thank you, but what about if I have 3-6 script files, which are connected to one page, each script file consisting of DOMContentLoaded callback and one IIFE inside that callback?

Comment: @fujio if you keep your script files at the end of `body` then the `DOMContentLoaded` listener is not required. Each file will just have all code wrapped inside an IIFE.